# Get the video url from YouTube and strip off all the parameters

Tags: php, regex

Hello how can I delete anything of this string and have only the XBH1dcHoL6Y ?

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3">
```

My purpose is to have the url like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBH1dcHoL6Y
```

and this is what I found so far (but i can't delete the parameters)

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/v/6n8PGnc_cV4";
$start = strpos($url,"v=");
echo 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'.substr($url,$start+2);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's too bad they didn't use a proper `?query=string` or `parse_url()` would be magical for this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory one-liner:

```
echo end(explode('/', reset(explode('&', 'http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3'))));
```

**Edit:** [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) version:

```
$string = '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&-version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></embed>';

$expr = "/<embed.*https?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*<\/embed>/";

if(preg_match($expr, $string, $matches))
  echo 'Matched: '.$matches[1];
else
  echo 'No match';

// returns "Matched: XBH1dcHoL6Y"
```

Comment: Great, thanks. The string is in a post content and not all posts have an embed video. How can I recognize if the current one has?

Comment: What's the use case? The literal answer to your comment would be something similar to `if(strstr('<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/', $post_content)) echo 'Content contains movie';`, but I suspect you may actually want something more like [preg_match](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Hi there, can you please find me the error here?
`$string = '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></embed>';

preg_match('#<embed[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</embed>#s', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US";
$urlSplode = explode('/',$url);

$urlEnd = $urlSplode[count($urlSplode)-1];

$urlEndSplode = explode('&',$urlEnd);

$finalStr = $urlEndSplode[0];

echo "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$finalStr";
```

here is the demo:

http://codepad.org/aoGLZSX0

Answer (score 0):

```
$urlTokens = explode("/", "http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&version=3");  
$urlTokens = explode("&", $urlTokens[4]);
$url = $urlTokens[0]; // will output XBH1dcHoL6Y
```

Comment: basically the same answer ^_^

Comment: Fixed. Yep, it's the same solution, didn't see your answer!

Comment: Great, thanks. The string is in a post content and not all posts have an embed video. How can I recognize if the current one has?

Comment: I would try with `if (strpos('youtube.com', $postContentString) !== false)`, where `$postContentString` is the HTML or your post contained in a string. strpos function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php